# svnkit: how to get latest revision number from SVN DB?

Tags: java, svnkit

I want to get the latest revision number of the SVN database using SVNKIT. I don't want to update the local repository and get the head revision number , i want to directly contact the SVN repository and get the latest revision number. please help me .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DAVRepositoryFactory.setup();
String url = "(directory in svn url)";
String name = "(login name)";
String password = "(login password)";
SVNRepository repository = null;
repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIDecoded(url));
ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager =
                   SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(name, password);
repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
SVNDirEntry entry = repository.info(".", -1);
System.out.println("Latest Rev: " + entry.getRevision());
```

Comment: FWIW, the link is dead for me. But I found the exact same code [here](http://subversion.1072662.n5.nabble.com/getting-a-directory-s-latest-revision-number-td1734.html). (Not very important)

Answer (score 2):

```
FSRepositoryFactory.setup();
File pathToRepository = new File("/path/to/repository");
SVNRepository svnRepository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.fromFile(pathToRepository));
try {
    final long latestRevision = svnRepository.getLatestRevision();
    System.out.println("latestRevision = " + latestRevision);
} finally {
    svnRepository.closeSession();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DAVRepositoryFactory.setup();

final SVNURL url = SVNURL.parseURIDecoded("http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf");
final SVNRepository repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(url);
final long latestRevision = repository.getLatestRevision();
System.out.println(latestRevision);
```